# Change dynamically the Data Base - Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am developing an application with login centered for more than 150 database of different and i can only wonder what is the database that i use when it is done a post to login , in all the examples that I saw on the internet to change dynamically with a database of nothing comes close to my problem, will be that someone can help to develop a solution to change dynamically the database when I get the post to login.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you looked at https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html ?

Comment: Yes i saw but for this had to put 150 database in the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and use `EntityManagers` dynamically:

```
$connection = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection([
  // connection parameters stored in config or other database
]);
$config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createConfiguration($env);
// additional configuration e.g. of entities
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connection, $config);
```

And your `EntityManager` is ready.

Comment: I can then use this connection to the rest of the project?

Comment: Yes, you can put this code into a service and use / inject it anywhere you want.

Comment: Note that this will not change your default entity manager but will create new one.

Comment: Thank you, will you could insert a complete example?